# how to force link open on a new tab on iFrame?

Tags: html, iframe

I'm trying to make an iFrame with a page that includes many links inside, and when someone clicks a link the link should open on a new tab, but instead, it opens on the iframe. can you help me, please?

Here's the code

```
<iframe  src="https://www.google.com/search?q=google+speed+test&rlz=1C1OKWM_iwIL860IL860&oq=google&aqs=chrome.0.69i59j69i57j69i60l3j69i65l3.1015j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8" loading="lazy" target="_blank"></iframe>
```

Comment: Have you tried to use an attribute like `onclick="window.open('https://www.google.com/')"`?

Answer (score 2):

The `target` attribute needs to go on the `<a>` element or the `<base>` element in the document inside the frame.

You can't set link targets from the frame itself.

Comment: Let's say I want that any <a> will open on a new tab, how do I do it?

Comment: @R.Idan — The same way you are trying to do with the iframe in the code you have. You put a `target` attribute on it.

Answer (score 0):

here an exemple of how an `<a>` will be open in new tab

```
 <a href="https://www.URL.com" target="_blank">URL</a>
```